# thymeleaf Attribute "?" appears more than once in element

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm trying to encapsulate some often-used HTML code into a thymeleaf element:

```
<div th:fragment="myField" class="mb-3">
    <label th:for="${field}" th:text="#{${label}}"></label>
    <input th:type="${type==null ? 'text': type}" [[${required==null ? '':'required']][[${disabled !=null ? 'disabled':'']] th:id="${field}" class="form-control">
    <small th:if="${info!=null}" class="form-text text-muted" th:text="#{${info}}"></small>
</div>
```

Which I will then call like so:

```
<div th:insert="~{fragments/myLayout :: myField}" th:with="field=name,label=person.name,required=true"></div>
```

I want to allow the parameters `type`, `required` and `disabled` to be empty in the `th:insert`.

However I'm getting an exception:

```
Malformed markup: Attribute "?" appears more than once in element
```

Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: Some notes in case they help: (1) This does not look right: `th:if="info!=null"`. The `${...}` appears to be missing. (2) I don't think you can use the `[[...]]` [expression inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#expression-inlining) syntax _inside_ an HTML tag. That syntax is equivalent to the _result_ from a `th:text` expression. Fixing that requires some restructuring of your fragment. But do you even need to mix these two different syntax approaches? Why use `[[...]]` at all, here?

Comment: Hi @andrewjames you're right I forgot the ${...} and have fixed the example. The expression inlining syntax does in fact work, but - as the exception says - I can only use it once. If there is a way to restructure the fragment I would like to know.

Comment: Similarly, I've tried with `th:attrappend="disabled=${disabled}?'disabled'"`. But if I use the same approach with both `disabled` and `required`, I get a similar exception: Malformed markup: Attribute "th:attrappend" appears more than once in element

Comment: Thymeleaf supports those boolean attributes (`required` and `disabled`) without you needing to use inline expressions. The documentation has an [overview with examples](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#fixed-value-boolean-attributes). So, in your scenario, something like `th:disabled="${disabled !=null ? true : false}"`. Or, even better, pass in a Java `true`/`false` boolean in your `disabled` variable - then you won't even need the Thymeleaf `? :`.

Comment: Thanks @andrewjames that's what I was looking for - I didn't know about boolean attributes. `th:required="${required!=null}" th:disabled="${disabled!=null}" ` works